# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Failed to read S3TransferUtility please check your setup or awsconfiguration.json file

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I have tried to upload a file to AWS s3 bucket using 'TransferUtility' and I have registered the app on Mobile HUB and pasted the 'awsconfiguration.json' file in res/raw as mentioned in the doc.

I got this LOG :

> I/AWSMobileClient: Welcome to AWS! You are connected successfully.

when I call this in 'onCreate()'

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this).execute();
```

I got this error when I execute this code

```
TransferUtility transferUtility =
                TransferUtility.builder()
                        .context(getApplicationContext())
                        .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                        .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider()))
                        .build();

TransferObserver uploadObserver =
                    transferUtility.upload(
                            s3Bucket+"/"+s3Folder+"/"+fileName,
                            new File(fileUrl));
```

ERROR :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: xxxx.xxxxx.com, PID: 28698
>                                                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to read S3TransferUtility
>   please check your setup or awsconfiguration.json file
>                                                                                  at
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility$Builder.build(TransferUtility.java:248)

Can anybody help me out of this and guide me on what I am doing wrong here.

Your effort is truly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you unblocked from this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The error you mentioned comes from here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/s3/transferutility/TransferUtility.java#L248

This error means that you have awsconfiguration.json file but you may not have `S3TransferUtility` block in the json file. Can you check if you have the required block in the json file?

Answer (score 2):

to elaborate on Karthikeyan's answer, a sample awsconfiguration.json looks like this

```
{
    "Version": "1.0",
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "COGNITO-IDENTITY-POOL-ID",
                "Region": "COGNITO-IDENTITY-POOL-REGION"
            }
        }
    },
    "IdentityManager" : {
      "Default" : { }
    },
    "S3TransferUtility": {
        "Default": {
            "Bucket": "S3-BUCKET-NAME",
            "Region": "S3-REGION"
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I was having was that the S3TransferUtility did not exist in my awsconfiguration.json file when I generated it. The reason being was that I had a bucket tied to my mobile-hub app however, I wanted to integrate with an existing bucket. Follow these directions to integrate to an existing bucket https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-integrate-an-existing-bucket.html

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you initialized the mobileClient instance and configuration file has default options in s3 block, then only you can able to access configuration.

```
private void initializeAwsMClient() {
    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, awsStartupResult ->
        Timber.d("AWSMobileClient is instantiated and you are connected to AWS!"))
        .execute();
}
```